# node js /foo route cant res.send value to front end

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js

I have a minimal nodejs server that loads an html page. In that page I have a javascript function that gets called every time the page is loaded. My goal is that every time the page gets loaded, my front-end makes a request to my back-end route '/getColors' which will return a value (using placeholder string for now).

I have my routing and everything set up and working, my backend /getColors route gets called and I try to return a dummy var with `res.send('dummyVar')` but I can't receive this string on my front end.

Am I missing some step with routing? I am using express and handlebars. My server.js file looks like this:

```
//setup express app
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var router = express.Router();

//port and hosting info
const port = 3000;
var host = '0.0.0.0';

//Loads the handlebars module
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');

//Sets our app to use the handlebars engine
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

//Sets handlebars configurations (we will go through them later on)
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({
    layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts',
    helpers: {
        'compare': function (lvalue, operator, rvalue, options) {

            var operators, result;
            
            if (arguments.length < 3) {
                throw new Error("Handlerbars Helper 'compare' needs 2 parameters");
            }
            
            if (options === undefined) {
                options = rvalue;
                rvalue = operator;
                operator = "===";
            }
            
            operators = {
                '==': function (l, r) { return l == r; },
                '===': function (l, r) { return l === r; },
                '!=': function (l, r) { return l != r; },
                '!==': function (l, r) { return l !== r; },
                '<': function (l, r) { return l < r; },
                '>': function (l, r) { return l > r; },
                '<=': function (l, r) { return l <= r; },
                '>=': function (l, r) { return l >= r; },
                'typeof': function (l, r) { return typeof l == r; }
            };
            
            if (!operators[operator]) {
                throw new Error("Handlerbars Helper 'compare' doesn't know the operator " + operator);
            }
            
            result = operators[operator](lvalue, rvalue);
            
            if (result) {
                return options.fn(this);
            } else {
                return options.inverse(this);
            }
        
        }
        

      }
}));

//Tells app to use '/public' folder for static files
app.use(express.static('public'))

//connect all routes
const routes = require('./routes');
app.use('/', routes);

//use this folder for static files
app.use('/static/', express.static(__dirname + '/static/'));

//render and startup server
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening to port ${port}`));
```

It sends all routes to index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var router = express.Router();


//tagger.site route
app.get('/tagger', function (req, res) {
  res.render('newtagger', {
      layout : 'newHomeindex', 
      pageTitle: 'tagger.site',
      projectsTab:'active',
      icon: 'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/48-bubbles/48/06.Tags-512.png'
    });
})

app.post('/getColors', function(req, res){
  //let filepath = req.body.filepath
  console.log("/getColors route " )
  //res.send('hello world')
  res.send('value')
});

module.exports = app;
```

The html page that gets loaded has this  tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        getColors()

        //make request to colors backend
        function getColors(){
            console.log("getColors()")

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/getColors',
                data: {
                    type: "varValue",
                },
            }).then(async function (data) {
                console.log("REQUESTDONE data = ", data)
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log("REQUESTDONE err = ", err)
            })
        }
    });

</script>
```

When my page first gets loaded, I can see `getColors()` printed in my chrome console, so I know that the function is getting called correctly. In my terminal, I can see `/getColors route` get printed out, so I know the backend function is getting called. But I never get to see 'REQUESTDONE' printed in my chrome console. Meaning the request never gets received, am I returning the string with res.send() incorrectly, or am I capturing this value in my front end ajax request incorrectly? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "it sends all routes to index.js"?

Comment: what is the content of routes.js ?

Comment: In chrome dev tools network inspect the actual response body of the request ( and status, url etc) for clues to start narrowing down where the problem is

Comment: JQuery AJAX does not return a ``promise``. Instead, it returns a ``promise`` *like* object. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/